# How to transform column into row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a attendance table like this:

```
Student_id   attendance_date    status
-----------  ----------------   ---------
       1     1/8/2014          Present
       2     1/8/2015          Absent
       1     2/8/2014          Present
       2     2/8/2015          Present
       1     3/8/2014          Present
       2     3/8/2015          Present
```

Expected output is this:

```
  Student_ id   1/8/2014      2/8/2014     3/8/2014
 -------------  ---------     ---------   ----------
         1     present         present      present
         2     absent          present      present
```

Please help me to get a expected output.....

Comment: You are looking for `pivot`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a procedure and use Dynamic Pivot for this like below.

```
DECLARE @dates NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get all the dates to pivot
SELECT @dates = ISNULL(@dates  + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(attendance_date)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT attendance_date FROM attendance) AS attendance 

--Construct the dynamic pivot query

SET @query = 
  N'SELECT status, ' + @dates + '
    FROM attendance
    PIVOT(MAX(status) 
          FOR dates IN (' + @dates + ')) AS pivotTable'

-- excecute the dynamic query

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: You need format the date strings as well, particularly `FOR dates IN...` here you are comparing a date or datetime value to a string. And include a date range filter in both the query that sets the @dates and the @query values.

Answer (score 0):

may be this works

```
SELECT   t.[user_id], t.[attendance_date],t.[status] 
     FROM    Attendance t 
 PIVOT   ( MIN(status) 
      FOR attendance_date IN ([1/8/2014],[2/8/2014],[3/8/2014]) ) pvt;
```

Comment: i am getting following error:----Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.